# Libgdx Make Lights Ignore Bodies

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I have a libgdx game in the works with Box2d and Box2d Lights.

My questions is how do I get Bodys / Bodydefs to ignore the light source from a Box2d Light and not cast shadows?

Thanks.

```
  PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();
  groundBox.setAsBox(2f, 2f);

  FixtureDef gridBox = new FixtureDef();
  gridBox.shape = groundBox;
  gridBox.density = 1.0f;

  gridBox.filter.groupIndex = GRID_GROUP;
  gridBox.filter.categoryBits = GRID_CAT;
  gridBox.filter.maskBits = GRID_MASK;

  bodyDefs[i][j] = new BodyDef();       
  bodyDefs[i][j].position.set(j*factor + factor, i*factor + factor);
  bodyDefs[i][j].fixedRotation = true;
  bodyDefs[i][j].type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

  bodies[i][j] = world.createBody(bodyDefs[i][j]);
  bodies[i][j].createFixture(gridBox);

  handler = new RayHandler(world);
  handler.setCombinedMatrix(camera.combined);
  Filter filter = new Filter();
  filter.groupIndex = GRID_GROUP; // GRID_GROUP = 1
  filter.categoryBits = GRID_CAT; // GRID_CAT = 0x0001;
  filter.maskBits = GRID_MASK;    // GRID_MASK = 1;

  new PointLight(handler, 1000, Color.RED, 2000, 0, height);

  PointLight.setContactFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Have you managed this to work? I have the same issue. Could you share you solition or hint?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following method :

cone.setContactFilter(**categoryBits**, **groupIndex**, **maskBits**);

where cone is an object of type **ConeLight**. Now this light will ignore the bodies having the 
specified categoryBits,groupIndex and the maskBits.

You can set the categoryBits,groupIndex and the maskBits through the body's fixture in the 
following manner-

**fixture.filter.categoryBits** = your value;

(categoryBits : The collision category bits. Normally you would just set one bit.)

**fixture.filter.groupIndex** = your value;

( groupIndex: Collision groups allow a certain group of objects to never collide (negative) or always collide (positive). Zero means 
 no collision group. Non-zero group filtering always wins against the mask bits.)

**fixture.filter.maskBits** = your value

(maskBits:The collision mask bits. This states the categories that this shape would accept for collision.)

If you wish some bodies to ignore ALL LIGHTS.then you can use the following
**Light**.setContactFilter(categoryBits, groupIndex, maskBits)

Comment: I assume this is the correct Method, but i'm having issues implementing it. I've updated my question to help clear the air.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the contact filters can only be applied to ALL LIGHTS using Box2D Lights. I tried to set them using the setContactFilter method that aug13 refers to, but that is a static method that is inherited from Light and cannot be called from an object. I don't know if it could at some point in the past.

From the docs:

```
public static void setContactFilter(short categoryBits,
                    short groupIndex,
                    short maskBits)
```

create new contact filter for ALL LIGHTS with give parameters